# Number of seconds from 1st January 1900 to start of Unix epoch

Tags: time

I need to report a time in seconds since 1st January 1900.  I have the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch.

Can anybody point me to a definitive reference to the number of seconds between 1/1/1900 and 1/1/1970?

Comment: Which calendar? Note that Jan 1st 1900 falls on very different dates in Julian and Gregorian calendars. This is relevant as both were widely used at that time. Also, what timezone? The Epoch starts at 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC**. Other than that, (number of days in non-leap years*number of seconds in a day*number of non-leap years) + (number of days in leap years*number of seconds in a day*number of leap years)

Comment: Good question... let's say Gregorian.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to the Time protocol in RFC 868 it is 2208988800L.

The Time

The time is the number of seconds since 00:00 (midnight) 1 January 1900
GMT, such that the time 1 is 12:00:01 am on 1 January 1900 GMT; this
base will serve until the year 2036.

For example:

the time  2,208,988,800 corresponds to 00:00  1 Jan 1970 GMT,

```
         2,398,291,200 corresponds to 00:00  1 Jan 1976 GMT,

         2,524,521,600 corresponds to 00:00  1 Jan 1980 GMT,

         2,629,584,000 corresponds to 00:00  1 May 1983 GMT,

    and -1,297,728,000 corresponds to 00:00 17 Nov 1858 GMT.
```

Comment: When I add 2208988800 value to seconds since epoch value of *nix, I get seconds since 01.01.1970 correctly. Thanks

Comment: Year 2036? 2038!

Comment: Yes Mohammad, RFC 868 and RFC 5905 wrap in 2036.  Unix dates wrap around in 2038.  The question was number of seconds from 1900 to Unix Epoch.

Answer (score 9):

70 years = 2,208,988,800 seconds, 01-01-1900 00:00 to 01:01-1970 00:00

Comment: Does that include leap years?

Comment: Leap years, yes, but not time zones, daylight savings or leap seconds.

Comment: AFAIK, leap seconds have only been announced since 1972, so we needn't worry about those.