# Function for returning number of seconds since 1/1/1900

Tags: time, linux-kernel

Is there a function in the kernel for converting a `timespec` as returned from eg `do_gettimeofday` to the number of seconds since 1/1/1900 in a "64-bit unsigned fixed-point number" as described in [RFC 1305](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1305.txt)?

Comment: Excuse me while I rant, but do you *actually* expect us to build your project **for** you, step by step? Your last question gave you an answer for converting to Unix Epoch time; surely adding/subtracting two numbers is within your intellectual ability? (see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805832/number-of-seconds-from-1st-january-1900-to-start-of-unix-epoch )

Comment: No, of course I don't expect anybody to build anything for me!  But this is a question and answer site, and I as far as I know there is no rule against asking two related questions in quick succession.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's not *wrong*, per se, but it is good manners to #1 try solving the problem yourself first, and then #2 show what you have tried, what worked, what didn't and how. Asking for help at every single step of your way, without even a hint of effort at `#1`, smells very much like "gimme the codez", split into bite-sized chunks. I'm not saying this *is* your case, but without #2, it's hard to tell apart from the hordes of copy-and-pasters.

Comment: Fine -- note that I'm not asking for how to convert the timespec structure to a number, but whether there's a kernel function that will do this for me.

Comment: the kernel doesn't really bother with presentation logic, so: no. Should be simple to convert into this from Unix time, no?

Comment: Yes, I know it's simple...  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with what you want.  However to see what your kernel is doing 
Try a search like this:

```
http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=adjtimex%20lang:%5Ec$&type=cs
```

This should return the code for directly reading and seting the kernel's internal time keeping data for your box.  You will have to scroll thru a lot of listings.

npt uses what amounts to a struct timeval, two 32 bit unsigned integers, one tracks seconds, the other tracks fractions of a second, since 01 Jan 1900.  The fractions tracked are different in ntp vs the timeval struct.

One of issues is: are you using 32 or 64 bit time & date api's?  Note that 1900 is NOT representable to the 32 bit api (This is 32 bit Linux output, using TZ=UTC)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void ptime(char *dest, time_t *lt)
{
   strftime(dest, 80, "%c", localtime(lt));
   printf("%08x(%010u): %s\n", *lt, *lt, dest);
}

int main(void)
{
   char tmp[80]={0x0};
   time_t lt[8]={1, 0xffffffff, 0x7fffffff, 0x80000000, 0}, *p=lt;
   while(*p) ptime(tmp, p++);
   return 1;
}
output:
00000001(0000000001): Thu Jan  1 00:00:01 1970
ffffffff(4294967295): Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 1969
7fffffff(2147483647): Tue Jan 19 03:14:07 2038
80000000(2147483648): Fri Dec 13 20:45:52 1901
```

Note the start and end times.  They do not have anything to do with 1900.  64 bit api's also miss 1900 in a different way.

The ntp protocol marches to the beat of its own drum.  It starts with 0 seconds and will "run out" of time (like the Y2K problem) somewhere in 2037.

I would look up the C code xntp or ntp and use their representations, but don't expect to be able to do anything with it using your Linux time & date api.  You will have to query an ntp server to get what you want reliably.