# Periscope timestamps

Tags: android, c++

When I perform the following request: POST https://signer.periscope.tv/sign HTTP/1.1 in Periscope app it generates 3 timestamps.

Below are 3 examples of those timestamps, but I can't figure out what they mean.

I know that number 3 is always the Linux timestamp, but what are 1 & 2 and how are they related to the Linux timestamp?

What is "tpForBroadcasterFrame" and how is related to timestamp?

- 1 ntpForBroadcasterFrame: 15704244410975025152
- 2 ntpForLiveFrame             : 15704244125303865344
- 3 timestamp                        : 1447440545

  #
- 1 ntpForBroadcasterFrame: 15704244443861590016
- 2 ntpForLiveFrame             : 15704244125303865344
- 3 timestamp                        : 1447440553

  #
- 1 ntpForBroadcasterFrame: 15704244474141110272
- 2 ntpForLiveFrame             : 15704244125303865344
- 3 timestamp                        : 1447440560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two look to be [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) time stamps. The third one is more correctly called a POSIX timestamp.

NTP stores data in an unsigned 64 bit integer that represents 32 bits of seconds since 1900 and 32 bits of fractional seconds, so...

Masking off the first 32 bits of 15704244410975025152 gives 3656429334 seconds since 1900. The other 32 bits have no mapping to a POSIX timestamp as its minimum resolution is 1 second.

Subtracting 2208988800, [the number of seconds between 1900 and 1970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805832/number-of-seconds-from-1st-january-1900-to-start-of-unix-epoch), from 3656429334 gives 1447440534 seconds since the Posix epoch, or Fri, 13 Nov 2015 18:48:54 GMT

Quick hack code:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr uint64_t epochdelta = 2208988800L; // number of seconds between 1900 and 1970

int main()
{
    uint64_t num= 15704244410975025152ULL;

    uint32_t seconds  = (uint32_t)(num >> 32);


    std::cout << seconds << " seconds since 1900"  << std::endl;
    std::cout << seconds - epochdelta << " seconds since 1970" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```