# How to generate time like ntp?

Tags: php, ntp

How to generate time NTP like 15715846074689084456?
I know this time is generated between 1900 and 1970.

Comment: "  NTP timestamps are represented as a 64-bit unsigned fixed-point number, in seconds relative to 0h on 1 January 1900. "

Comment: I know but i did not find how to do it on php and find this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770024/periscope-timestamps