# C how to printf date and time to plot in excel

Tags: excel, date, plot, time, printf

I have a basic C code that records temperature values to a text file.  I record at a resolution of a value every minute.  So I would like to be able to simply open my text file, written by my C code, and select columns A and B and just graph in Excel, then print.

Problem is how should I print out date and time that is excel readable, so I can plot it in excel in the least amount of mouse clicks and then print it out on the printer?

*I understand this is primarly a windows excel question... but... I wrote C code and ready to punch the monitor for not having been able to reasonably figure out in excel to have my plot with X axis as date/time.  At best I make a middleman column of 1..n to use as the X axis to just generate the plot.  And i'm stuck using excel, because I also need windows in order to print to the printer.*

here is how I am currently printing out to my file, this is data extracted from Dell's `racadm getsensorinfo` so I can track server room temperature.

```
      Date       Time    SystemBoardInletTemp°F   SystemBoardExhaustTemp°F
2022-10-13   13:17:01                        66                         84
2022-10-13   13:18:01                        66                         84
2022-10-13   13:19:01                        66                         84
2022-10-13   13:20:01                        66                         82
```

it struck me later that what I really want is how to print a column of numbers that is in excel date format, so column A is my "2022-10-13" and column B is "13:17:01" and column C would be that column A & B data in excel format... to make excel happy such that I simply select columns C and D and graph.

I use time.h to get the current date + time when my C code is run... is there some function in time.h or any other .h that I can use to printf a excel format of date+time ? It's not epoch is it?

the C code I currently have to print out date & time in human readable format is this

```
time_t epoch;
struct tm tm;

epoch = time( NULL );
tm = *localtime( &epoch );

printf( "%d-%02d-%02d",  tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday );
printf( "   %02d:%02d:%02d", tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
```

**how can I printf a date time value that is in excel readable format for plotting in excel?**

Comment: Looks like you’d need to write a column which contained an Excel serial date. How do you get the date and time now? Can you parse it and perform calculations on it to convert?

Comment: I use time.h to get date and time, using code that has been posted within stackoverflow on how to get that.  I edited my post above see text at the bottom

Comment: I added updated text to the above

Comment: for example `10/19/2022  10:32:00 AM` is `44853.43889` in excel.  how can I get to that number in C code to print out that kind of corresponding value?

Comment: off the top of my head, I don’t know. Something like `(double)(time() + 2208988800L) / 86400.0` Might work. The number comes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805832/number-of-seconds-from-1st-january-1900-to-start-of-unix-epoch

Answer (score 1):

**Excel stores date** as a decimal number of days since Jan 1, 1900, as opposed to linux epoch time which is from Jan 1, 1970.

And the excel numerical format for date+time is `days since 1/1/1900`**.**`fraction of the day`

for example `10/19/2022` shows up in an adjacent cell if formatted as number as `44853.00000`

if you put in `1/1/1900` then the number value is `1.00000`

The value after the decimal point is the number of seconds so far into the current day divided by 86400 (because there are 86400 seconds in a day), so

midnight == `00:00:00` is `0.00000`

10:33 AM with no corresponding date is 0.4395833 because that is `[ (10*60*60) + (33*60) ] / 86400`

so `10/19/2022 10:33 AM` is `44853.4395833`

I suppose for this year and going forward, `1/1/2022` is `44562.0` in excel so I could calculate the number of days since then and just hard code `44562` as the starting value to work from.

Although it seems excel is happy if I printf the date as `10/13/2022 10:33:01 AM` with that exact spacing... a file open in excel immediately recognizes that as one column as a date with time that it is happy to plot and is sufficient for my needs.  So you don't necessarily have to explicitly print a column of numerical date+time values as I described.

**note:** my excel under office 365 shows `Jan 1, 1900` as `1.0` and `Jan 1, 1901` as 367.0 which seems to contradict 1900 not being a leap year, as stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-a-leap-year

so be careful if you decide to calculate the numerical values of days since jan 1, 1900 based on the leap year rule of year evenly divisible by 100 also must be evenly divisible by 400.